# What is the entry point (app level) when creating an app in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, sqlite, swift4

I'm creating an iOS app that stores contact number in sqlite database (mini project). From the functional wise, it works good but I don't really follow the MVC pattern. I created the table in the `viewDidLoad()` function in the root viewcontroller but my superior said that it was not a good practice. He said that I have to "put the create the table part in the app level or the entry point of the app". I don't know where that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you will want to put your app's initialization code in the `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` method of AppDelegate class. This class is defined in *AppDelegate.swift* file that is created by default in every iOS project. If you never touched it, it will look like this:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

I think this is what your superior meant when they was speaking about the entry point.